# Есть ли необходимость прописывать в action $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?

Tags: php

```
<form action = '<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?>' method='post'>
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, обязан ли я писать строку, которая написана в `action`? Потому что я не видел не какой разницы если я её не пишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае можно написать так:

```
<form method='post'>
```

Comment: значит то что написанно в action не обезательно да?

Comment: @AndrewKourilenko: Данные в таком случае отправятся на текущий URL. Если ваш обработчик формы, модель, скрипт или что там у вас находится по другому адресу, то необходимо явно указать URL.